# Android app crashes on start when deployed with buildozer

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I'm writing an Android application under Python 2.7 using the Kivy library and buildozer to build/deploy it to the Android device. The device in question is an Asus ZenPad 3s 10, with the debugging options turned on. It is NOT rooted, as I understand this device can't be rooted at the moment.

I can build the apk, but when I run `buildozer android deploy run logcat > log.txt`, the application never gets past the Kivy splashscreen on the tablet, with the only message being "*ETS Demo has stopped*".

In the log, the cause of the problem seems to me to be given by the lines:

```
--------- beginning of crash  
08-03 18:39:41.807   441   441 F libc    : unable to stat file for the executable "/system/bin/sh": Permission denied  
08-03 18:39:41.807   441   441 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 441 (sh)  
08-03 18:39:41.807   441   441 F libc    : Unable to open connection to debuggerd: Connection refused
```

I don't know what these mean, and I haven't been able to find anyone with a similar problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my buildozer.spec file:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = ETS Demo

# (str) Package name
package.name = etsdemo

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.innodem

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,dat

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy,numpy,scipy,dlib,opencv,scikit-image,scikit-learn,imutils

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = landscape

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = CAMERA,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
p4a.bootstrap = sdl2


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

And here is the log file

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.18.4 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'pip install -q --user "appdirs" "colorama>=0.3.3" "sh>=1.10" "jinja2" "six"'
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/alexandre/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/alexandre/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /home/alexandre/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=etsdemo --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy,numpy,scipy,dlib,opencv,scikit-image,scikit-learn,imutils --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/alexandre/Desktop/Demo/.buildozer/android/platform/build'
# Cwd /home/alexandre/Desktop/Demo/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
# Run '/home/alexandre/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/platform-tools/adb devices'
# Cwd None
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
H1NPCV026140PM7 device

# Deploy on H1NPCV026140PM7
# Run '/home/alexandre/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/platform-tools/adb install -r "/home/alexandre/Desktop/Demo/bin/ETSDemo-0.1-debug.apk"'
# Cwd /home/alexandre/.buildozer/android/platform
# Application pushed.
# Run on H1NPCV026140PM7
# Run '/home/alexandre/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/platform-tools/adb shell am start -n org.innodem.etsdemo/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity -a org.kivy.android.PythonActivity'
# Cwd /home/alexandre/.buildozer/android/platform
Starting: Intent { act=org.kivy.android.PythonActivity cmp=org.innodem.etsdemo/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity }
# Application started.
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.18.4 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Run '/home/alexandre/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/platform-tools/adb logcat '
# Cwd /home/alexandre/.buildozer/android/platform
--------- beginning of crash
08-03 18:39:41.807   441   441 F libc    : unable to stat file for the executable "/system/bin/sh": Permission denied
08-03 18:39:41.807   441   441 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 441 (sh)
08-03 18:39:41.807   441   441 F libc    : Unable to open connection to debuggerd: Connection refused
08-03 18:39:41.827   449   449 F libc    : unable to stat file for the executable "/system/bin/sh": Permission denied
08-03 18:39:41.827   449   449 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 449 (sh)
08-03 18:39:41.827   449   449 F libc    : Unable to open connection to debuggerd: Connection refused
08-03 18:39:41.840   451   451 F libc    : unable to stat file for the executable "/system/bin/sh": Permission denied
08-03 18:39:41.840   451   451 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 451 (sh)
08-03 18:39:41.840   451   451 F libc    : Unable to open connection to debuggerd: Connection refused
```

EDIT:
Here is a link to the full log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1jpg2jx2ddxqul0/log.txt?dl=0

I am building on Ubuntu 16.04. My hardware specs are as follow:

- Memory: 16.6 GiB
- Processor: Intel Core i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz x 8
- Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on NV126
- OS type: 64-bit

The tablet I am trying to deploy to is running Android 7.0. I can't say much about the app as I am under an NDA, but it involves facial feature recognition using the mobile device's camera. I am not using scipy directly, but I included it in the requirements list because other libraries I am using depend on it.

I'm having issues getting an emulator to work on my system. I'll update the post as soon as I get it working.

Comment: Please edit your question to include: OS/CPU you are building on, which version of Android your tablet is using, a description of what kind of app is it (as I see references to scipy and opencv in the script) and what happens if you tried to build and deploy to a emulator.

Comment: Post the full logcat log.